# Is there a concept like late binding in in jsf

Tags: jsf, binding, primefaces

I have a dialog which includes an XHTML page that has a panel with binding variable set.. I wanted to know if there is a way to call that panel after the dialog is called and not before

```
<p:panelGrid id="ruleSeqPanelId" binding="#{gssociatedBean.SequencePanel}"
```

Comment: No, there isn't. You need to look in a different direction for the solution. As you didn't tell anything about the concrete functional requirement for which you incorrectly thought that this would be the possible solution, it's not possible to post a suited answer to that.

Comment: Have you tried `dynamic="true"` on the dialog? That should keep the dialog (and it's contents) from being loaded until it's shown.

Comment: I have a table of objects, to get more info we can click on the view link which opens a dialog.. this dialog has a panel with the binding set. I want this binding to happen only after the dialog has popped out... I'll take a shot with the dynamic attribute.

Comment: dynamic="true" didnt work

Comment: @BalusC what if I wanted to add values to that panel using the backing bean,<p:panelGrid id="ruleSeqPanelId"/> how do i do it please do reply

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue by adding a condition to the ui:include tag ie

```
<ui:include src="#{bean.state=='somevalue'?'a.xhtml':'b.xhtl'/>
```

so my page that has the binding attribute will be set only when the particular condition is satisfied other wise a dummy page is shown. This resolved my issue